# Adding exif dates and times to images

Tags: python, exif

I have a few hundred photos which are missing the correct `createdate` field.
I need this so that when I upload them to Google Photos, they'll be sorted correctly.

Fortunately almost all of the photos have another date field which is correct, either `datetimeoriginal` or `modifydate` or something.

I was hoping to use the python `exif` module to scan the files, find the date field with the oldest time and use that to add the `createdate` field. Unfortunately that module doesn't seem to like adding new exif fields where they don't already exist. It errors out with:

```
RuntimeError: only can add GPS IFD to image, not exif
```

What other options do I have for adding the missing fields? Preferably using Python, but Ruby or Go would be OK too :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely should look at [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org) command-line util.
It's quite powerful, so probably it's possible not to write script at all.

Even if it would be hard to batch-process your task, you could call exiftool from Python with `subprocess` module ( `subprocess.call(["exitfool", "param1", "param2"])`/`subprocess.check_output(["exitfool", "param1", "param2"])`).

Here's my attempt to approach your problem (command-line):

We have a photo `test.HEIC`. Let's look at its date-related EXIF:

```
Olhas-MBP:Downloads olia$ exiftool test.HEIC  | grep Date

File Modification Date/Time     : 2020:07:19 21:41:19+03:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2020:07:19 21:41:19+03:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2020:07:19 21:41:19+03:00
Modify Date                     : 2020:03:30 11:41:02
Date/Time Original              : 2020:03:30 11:41:02
Create Date                     : 2020:03:30 11:41:02
Profile Date Time               : 2017:07:07 13:22:32
Create Date                     : 2020:03:30 11:41:02.891+03:00
Date/Time Original              : 2020:03:30 11:41:02.891+03:00
Modify Date                     : 2020:03:30 11:41:02+03:00
```

So, this photo has both `Create Date` and `Modify Date`. Let's set "Create Date" to now:

```
exiftool -r -all= -createdate=now "-exif:createdate<createdate" -overwrite_original test.HEIC
    1 image files updated
```

Now, let's see the updated tags:

```
Olhas-MBP:Downloads olia$ exiftool test.HEIC | grep Date
File Modification Date/Time     : 2020:07:19 21:51:52+03:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2020:07:19 21:51:53+03:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2020:07:19 21:51:52+03:00
Create Date                     : 2020:07:19 21:51:52+03:00
Profile Date Time               : 2017:07:07 13:22:32
```

Now, let's set "Create Date" to "Modify Date" (not sure if I chose the correct tags actually):

```
Olhas-MBP:Downloads olia$ exiftool -r -all= -createdate=now "-FileModifyDate<FileCreateDate" -overwrite_original test.HEIC
    1 image files updated

Olhas-MBP:Downloads olia$ exiftool test.HEIC | grep Date
File Modification Date/Time     : 2020:07:19 21:53:19+03:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2020:07:19 21:54:09+03:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2020:07:19 21:54:08+03:00
Create Date                     : 2020:07:19 21:54:08+03:00
Profile Date Time               : 2017:07:07 13:22:32

Olhas-MBP:Downloads olia$ exiftool -r -all= -createdate=now "-FileModifyDate<CreateDate" -overwrite_original test.HEIC
    1 image files updated

Olhas-MBP:Downloads olia$ exiftool test.HEIC | grep Date
File Modification Date/Time     : 2020:07:19 21:54:08+03:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2020:07:19 21:54:51+03:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2020:07:19 21:54:50+03:00
Create Date                     : 2020:07:19 21:54:50+03:00
Profile Date Time               : 2017:07:07 13:22:32
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.